# ios 7.1.1 canvas drawImage memory leak

Tags: javascript, ios, canvas, memory-leaks

If i

```
    ctx.drawImage(anotherCanvas, clipX, clipY, clipW, clipH, x, y, w, h);
```

on an animation frame, i seem to get a huge memory leak till either IOS safari or chrome crash. If i do not clip the canvas and just draw it straight on, there is no leak.

```
    ctx.drawImage(anotherCanvas, x, y, w, h);
```

Problem is i need to be able to clip.
This ONLY seems to happen on IOS. Does anybody know why this is happening?

As for a workaround does anyone know a good way to force garbage collection / clear the memory build-up.

Any and all help much appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this problem, too. I think it's a bug from 7.1.1. As for the workaround -- you just said it. :\

Edit: Hmm... actually I take that back. What I had was an audio memory leak.

Comment: Yeah seems that way. Unfortunately i need to be able to clip.

Comment: One slow workaround until Apple fixes this horrific issue -- per-pixel copy.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem on IOS 9.0.1

The only workaround I found was to reduce the size of "anotherCanvas"

```
var maxRes = Math.min(canvas.width(), canvas.height());

var ratio = Math.min(
    ratioWidth = maxRes / anotherCanvas.width,
    ratioHeight = maxRes / anotherCanvas.height
);
anotherCanvas.width = anotherCanvas.width * ratio;
anotherCanvas.height = anotherCanvas.width * ratio;

clipX = clipX * ratio;
clipY = clipY * ratio;
clipW = clipW * ratio;
clipH = clipH * ratio;
```

I don't know why but with those values, the image quality is reduced but the page no longer crashes.